# Return a String to Controller from a View

Tags: c#, string, xaml, object, non-static

My project structure looks like this:

```
Solution-->Project-->Views-->Name.xaml-->Name.xaml.cs
                  -->Controllers-->NameController.cs
```

I'm trying to get string `name` from the `Views` folder. `name` is an .xaml file, and the string is in the back code.

I'm trying to do a simple `get` and `return` in NameController.cs to get string `name`. String `name` is the text from a textbox.

When I attempt this:

```
public string StringName
{
    get
    {
        return Views.Name.Namebox.Text;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, 
method, or property 'Project.Views.Name.Name'
```

Thank you for all of the help.

Edit:
Here's some pictures of my current `code`. 
[Textbox code](http://prntscr.com/4d70ml)--
[Underlying code](http://prntscr.com/4d70u9)--
[Controller code](http://prntscr.com/4d711o) <-- This code in unfinished on purpose. It doesn't even see `ProductId` as an object.

Comment: Is there a reason for this being downvoted?

Comment: Your receiving the error through your `Get`.  So it appears to have an issue, normally you should be able to do such an item without an issue.  I've received an error similar through a `Set`.  But does your textbox need `.Text` or `.Value` at the end?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I need the text from inside of it. So, I can assign it to a string, but I can't `get` that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear about what's going on: you're trying to access an instance value as if it were a static one.

So the question now becomes:

> How do I access an instance value?

The answer to which likely won't solve your problem:

> Instance values can only be accessed via an instance of the object.

So in the end, what you're really asking is this:

> How do I get an instance of my `ProductIdView` object?

You can go about it a number of different ways, but in the end it all comes down to you calling `new ProductIdView()` somewhere and then putting that reference someplace where it'll be in scope when you need it.

Comment: That is the most helpful answer I have ever had. I don't have a large sum of knowledge in programming. I think it's great you followed my thought process perfectly. Thank you so much.